# How can I call a library method from a contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, ethers.js

I'm currently looking at this contract (https://bscscan.com/address/0x05ff2b0db69458a0750badebc4f9e13add608c7f#code) (yes, I'm aware it's bsc and not eth, but functionally, they're the same).

Inside of it, there's a library called PancakeLibrary with a method called pairOf. I'm trying to call this method but I couldn't find anything for calling a library method in a contract using web3 or ethers in nodejs.

I've tried manually rewriting the contract and I've gotten this so far:

```
let factory = '0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F';
let address1 = '0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82';
let address2 = '0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c';
console.log(ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['uint32', 'string', 'bytes32', 'uint32'], ['0xff', factory, ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(['string','string'], [address1, address2]), '0xd0d4c4cd0848c93cb4fd1f498d7013ee6bfb25783ea21593d5834f5d250ece66']));
```

It's not working and I assume it's because the types I have aren't correct because changing them yields different results.

How can I either call the contract library method directly or rewrite it using ethers? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Usually to call a library you use `delegatecall`.